Upload files in In IntelliJ IDEA for specific modular Apps
Hello to every stackoverflow users , I working on some modular Apps that contain so many different module in Java , php and Producers in IntelliJ, they all in one project as module apps , backend wrote by java as service they have more than 8(now contain only 2) other apps module in maven , database wrote by oracle producers and UI(View) wrote with php for PWA , the problem is the service packaged as war file and upload to server via default run configuration(at this point I don't have any issue), BUT the php module I need uploaded to another server via ftp/sftp or ssh by action on save into default server.
at this point if set default server via ftp/sftp or ssh IntelliJ goes for upload whole projects into it! that I don't want And I need just upload the php project that can contain multi directories or files, How can I do for upload just php project without create sub project?
The Image shows part of my project View in IntelliJ.

As you can see I just need to upload default server the php module, not other projects via save action.
In other hand for explain more : I have multi module in one project and I need sprayed upload configuration after save action in IntelliJ.

i can do it with bash script or anything like that, but I need(find) something internal build in IntelliJ. exactly like save on action -> upload to default server.

thanks , look I can run my project via run config(create war ,,,) and save action upload files into default server but send all module into server! I just need tell intellij upload just this module.

I found it in, File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Deployment under Mappings can Specification which directory upload via ftp/sftp or ssh , so good that intellij had it.
